# from and to ranges in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause

Currently I have this kind of query

```
SELECT 
    part_number,
    part_name,
    attenuation_low_end,
    attenuation_high_end,
    optimum_fermentation_temp_f_low,
    optimum_fermentation_temp_f_high
FROM
    yeast_module 
WHERE 
    category = 3
AND
( 
    ( `attenuation_low_end` > '31' OR `attenuation_low_end` = '31' )
    
    AND 
    
    ( `attenuation_high_end` < '40' OR `attenuation_high_end` = '40' )
)
```

Where I'm trying to get the records with the range of `low to high end` from `31 and maximum of 40`

But it returns me something like this
[image]

As you can notice it seems doesn't return the data between `31` to `40`

Am I doing this right?

**UPDATE**

[image]

I'm expecting no return since, there's no data between 31-40

Comment: Tidbit: Most languages, including SQL, have `>=` and `<=` operators.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Tried that too but returns me same output

Comment: Of course it returns the same output. It's just a shorter way to write the same thing.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: What is the datatype of these columns? You're doing string comparisons instead of numeric comparisons. `'100' < '40'`

Comment: its a varchar hmm

Comment: @RaeIan Start by fixing that. To compare numeric values, store them as numbers and only convert to strings when you need to display them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want ranges contained in the 31-40 range:

```
where attenuation_low_end >= 31 and attenuation_high_end <= 40
```

If you want ranges that overlap the 31-40 range:

```
where attenuation_low_end <= 40 and attenuation_high_end >= 31
```

If your data is of a string datatype, then you need to convert the values to integers so they can be compared as such.

Containment:

```
where attenuation_low_end + 0 >= 31 and attenuation_high_end + 0 <= 40
```

Overlap:

```
where attenuation_low_end + 0 <= 40 and attenuation_high_end + 0 >= 31
```

Comment: This is the same as his query, just a more compact form.

Comment: I updated my post, Return should empty or null since there's no data between 31 - 40

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings, which performs lexicographic comparisons rather than numeric comparisons. You need to convert to numbers. Adding `0` to a numeric string is a simple way to convert it to a number.

```
WHERE 0+attenuation_low_end >= 31 AND 0+attenuation_high_end <= 40
```

Comment: Hello may I know the difference bet `WHERE 0+attenuation_low_end >= 31 AND 0+attenuation_high_end <= 40` and `where attenuation_low_end + 0 >= 31 and attenuation_high_end + 0 <= 40`

Comment: No difference. Addition is commutative.